# Heroku maintenance URL does not redirect

Tags: heroku

For test purposes, i have added the url http://google.com as the maintenance URL in heroku. When I turn the maintenance mode on and try to access my page, I get an ugly response instead of being redirected to google. Anyone else has that problem or do I not get something?

btw: the redirection to the error URL works just fine.

This is what I get as a response:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
      <style type="text/css">
        html, body, iframe { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; }
        iframe { display: block; width: 100%; border: none; }
      </style>
    <title>Offline for Maintenance</title></head>
    </head>
    <body>
      <iframe src="http://google.com">
        <p>Application Error</p>
      </iframe>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behavior, according to the Heroku support. They do not perform a redirect, but just include the page as an iframe into their own HTML file.

Too bad, that does not work so well if you host an API on Heroku that returns the responses in JSON or so.